# Changing Current Working Directory will not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

First time Python learner here, trying to change the current working directory of my project.
I can retrieve the default working directory, however attempting to change it proves harder.
I've tried all combinations but I keep getting 'None' as a response to my Print command of the new directory.

No idea what is going on

The code I tried was:

```
print ('----New Run----')
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
print ('Current Working Directory is: ', cwd)
cwd = os.chdir(r'C:\Users\danie\Documents\Programming\Python\Projects\test')
print ('New Working Directory is: ', cwd)
print ('----End Run----')
```

Responds with the following in Terminal:

> ----New Run----
> Current Working Directory is:  C:\Users\danie\Documents\Programming
> New Working Directory is:  None
> ----End Run----

I've also tried using

```
cwd = os.chdir('.\\Python\\Projects\\test')
```

To which yielded the same result.

Comment: `os.chdir()` does not return the new directory.  It doesn't need to, because obviously you already know the new directory name, because you passed it as the argument.

Comment: If `os.chdir()` does not raise an exception, then you can be sure it succeeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you get the changed directory.

Try this:

```
print ('----New Run----')
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
print ('Current Working Directory is: ', cwd)
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\danie\Documents\Programming\Python\Projects\test')
print ('New Working Directory is: ', os.getcwd())
print ('----End Run----')
```

The `chdir()` function only changes the directory. It doesn't return the current working directory. You need to use `getcwd()` seperately to get the new current working directory.

Comment: Thank you! This was it.
This is gonna be a long ride hahaha.